# Loading file with Tkinter returns IO error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8

So I am working on a tool which involves saving a file with Hex data.
What I want to happen is you save the file and it overwrites that file with stored hex data. However, I get an error which reads:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

I am using Tkinter's `asksaveasfile` to save the file, yet its class is loaded as `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`, when I want it to be `<class 'bytes'>`. How would I solve this?

```py
#Saving file
def savefile():
    filetypes = (
        ('level files', '*.level')
    )

   global content

   print(levelIcon.get()[0] + levelIcon.get()[1])

   savedFile = fd.asksaveasfile(defaultextension='.level',
                                filetypes= [('Level','.level')])
   if savedFile is None or filename is None or content is None:
       return

   print(type(savedFile))
   print(savedFile)
   print(content[1])
   with open(savedFile,"wb") as newFile:
       newFile.write(contents)
       newFile.close()
```

Comment: If you want a filename, use `asksaveasfilename()` which returns the selected filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile), you'll see that `asksaveasfile` does not return a filename.  It returns an opened file handle.  You just need to write to it.

```
savedFile = fd.asksaveasfile( ... )
savedFile.write(contents)
```